# Redirecting not working using .htaccess file from to the main domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains linked with my hosting, the first one is the main one that has this root: `public_html`, and the second one is an Addon domain that has this root: `public_html/lemerge`.

when the user enter `www.main-domain.com/lemerge` he access the second website. But I want to redirect the user to the main website instead of accessing the second website. So if the user enter `www.main-domain.com/lemerge` the user should be redirected to `www.main-domain.com`

I used redirects in cPanel to generate this code but it does not work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^main-domian\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.main-domian\.com$
RewriteRule ^lemerge\/?$ "http\:\/\/main-domian\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your **`/lemerge/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?main-domian\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: its worked but could you please tell me why when I put the code in /lemerge/.htaccess it works but when I put it in public_html/.htaccess it does not work ?

Comment: Because you might have some other rules in root htaccess as well. Also your regex should use .* after directory name.